# Tawarruk while praying

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, tashahhud

Assalamu alaikum

Is it mandatory to sit in the tawarruk or iftirash position while praying? because I am unable to sit that way while praying.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not mandatory. It is Sunnah.

Sitting in certain parts of prayer is mandatory according to consensus, and those are three:

- Sitting between the two sajdahs
- Sitting for the first tashahhud
- Sitting for the final tashahhud

But, the manner of sitting is not mandatory. It is Sunnah and Mustahabb.

But, leaving a Sunnah is no small matter. I suggest you really make sure why you think you are unable to do so when millions of Muslims around the world pray without trouble. If you do truly have an excuse rather than simply lack of effort, then know that the manner of sitting is not mandatory.